# Preciso criar colunas no phpmyadmin para cada checkbox que eu criei?

Tags: checkbox, phpmyadmin

Estou criando um site de hotel para um projeto escolar, e gostaria de saber se para cada `checkbox` que eu criei no código, terei que criar uma coluna no banco de dados do `phpmyadmin`? E como armazenar essa escolha do `checkbox` lá no banco de dados?

Obs: estou usando o `xampp`

```html
<div id="quartos">
       <div id="junior"> <input type="checkbox" name="quarto[]" value="op1"/> Suíte Júnior<br /></div>
       <div id="duplo"> <input type="checkbox" name="quarto[]" value="op2"/> Quarto Solteiro Duplo<br /></div>
       <div id="casal1"> <input type="checkbox" name="quarto[]" value="op3"/> Quarto Casal<br /></div>
       <div id="vista"> <input type="checkbox" name="quarto[]" value="op4"/> Apartamento Luxo vista para a cidade <br /></div>
       <div id="luxo1"> <input type="checkbox" name="quarto[]" value="op5"/> Apartamento Luxo <br /></div>
       <div id="master1"> <input type="checkbox" name="quarto[]" value="op6"/> Suíte Master <br /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nesse caso, iria sugerir usar radio button, pois o quarto pode ser apenas de uma opção (ou não?), e fazer uma coluna TIPO_QUARTO por exemplo.

Comment: Criar colunas ou inserir dados em colunas de uma tabela?

Comment: @RafaelWeber mudei para radio burron e criei a coluna do tipo de quarto. O que faço agora ?

Comment: Das opções que você colocou na `div id="quartos"`. O usuário pode apenas selecionar apenas um opção, correto?

Comment: Bom, pode seguir o que tem no [link] (https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Formul%C3%A1rio_PHP_%2B_Mysql)

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin sim

Answer (score 1):

O que vai decidir como os dados serão salvos no banco de dados, será o Modelo de Entidade e Relacionamento ([MER](http://www.devmedia.com.br/modelo-entidade-relacionamento-mer-e-diagrama-entidade-relacionamento-der/14332)) elaborado. Como mencionado na pergunta, você criou um site voltado para o ramo de hotelaria. E conforme o exemplo a seguir, podemos observar um MER do ramo de hotelaria.

Repare que o hospede tem uma relação com a reserva, que por sua vez com o quarto e o quarto com o tipo do quarto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem a seguir quem desenhou o MER indicou que a forma de guardar o tipo do quarto será através da relação, onde: 1 quarto possui 0 ou 1 tipo_quarto. E o tipo_quarto pode conter em 1 ou n(mais) quartos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sua questão é, como devo salvar o tipo do quarto escolhido pelo hospede? R: Seguindo a lógica de raciocínio desse MER, a tabela `quarto` terá uma *foreign key* da tabela `tipo_quarto`. Ou seja, você poderá seguir este conceito e criar uma tabela `tipo_quarto`, e toda vez que o hospede reservar um quarto, você derverá salvar o `id` ou `codigo`, conforme MER, da tabela `tipo_quarto` na tabela `quarto`.

Seria mais interessante você usar um select contendo as opções dos tipos de quartos e para cada `<option>` passar o id. Mas caso queira seguir com as `div's`, para cada `value=""` do `<input/>` deve conter um id.

Então seguindo a lógica apresentada. Você não precisará criar uma coluna no banco de dados para cada `tipo_quarto`. Caso tenha mais dúvidas só comentar.